# Why tkinter grid, columnconfigure and rowconfigure value not changing dynamically?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Please help anyone
You can read all details as an inline comment.

I have created three classes `LeftFrame`, `RightFrame`, `DynamicWindow`

In DynamicWindow I am inheriting RightFrame

### Step 1

LeftFrame, in column 0 with minsize 350

### Step 2

RightFrame, in column 1 with weight 1, capturing all available space

### Step 3

DynamicWindow, ingeriting RightFrame , Here is main problem, Please read the code.

```py
import tkinter as tk
from win32api import GetMonitorInfo, MonitorFromPoint

root = tk.Tk()
monitor_info = GetMonitorInfo(MonitorFromPoint((0, 0)))['Work']
root.geometry(f'{monitor_info[2]}x{monitor_info[3]}')
root.state('zoomed')
root.columnconfigure(0, minsize=350)  # Width of left frame
root.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)  # All available space for right frame
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)  # Full screen height for both frame

class LeftFrame(tk.Frame):
    """
    Left Frame
    """
    def __init__(self, container):
        super().__init__(container)
        self.config(bg='red')
        self.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')

class RightFrame(tk.Frame):
    """
    Right Frame:
        Divided into three section head frame, middle frame and bottom frame
        head frame contains button
        middle frame contains dynamically changeable frame. Here I am facing problem,
        frame not able to take actual size according to weight and minsize that I given.

    """
    def __init__(self, container):
        super().__init__(container)
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(0, minsize=30)
        self.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(2, minsize=30)
        self.config(bg='green')
        self.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='nsew')

        self.head_frame = tk.Frame(self, bg='orange')
        self.head_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
        self.head_frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.first_screen_button = tk.Button(self.head_frame, text='First Screen')
        self.first_screen_button.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew', ipadx=20)

        self.second_screen_button = tk.Button(self.head_frame, text='Second Screen')
        self.second_screen_button.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='nsew', ipadx=20)

        self.middle_frame = tk.Frame(self, bg='green')
        self.middle_frame.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='nsew')

        self.bottom_frame = tk.Frame(self, bg='orange')
        self.bottom_frame.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='nsew')

class DynamicWindow(RightFrame):
    def __init__(self, container):
        super().__init__(container)
        self.first_screen_button.config(command=self.first_screen)
        self.second_screen_button.config(command=self.second_screen)
        self.first_screen()  # I am calling this here becuase on first click on first screen button
        # window don't appear. You can check by comment this code.
        # Can anyone please tell me why first screen not appear on first click.

    def first_screen(self):
        """
        First screen that I want to appear when I click on button
        It has two frame
        """
        for widget in self.middle_frame.winfo_children():  
        # Want to destroy all available widget in middle frame
            widget.destroy()

        self.middle_frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)  
        # Configuring size and weight but this is not working properly
        self.middle_frame.columnconfigure(1, minsize=30)
        self.middle_frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.middle_frame.rowconfigure(1, weight=0)

        main_chart_window = tk.Frame(self.middle_frame, bg='#4d4d4d')
        main_chart_window.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')

        toolbar = tk.Frame(self.middle_frame, bg='red')
        toolbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='nsew')

    def second_screen(self):
        """
        This is not working in proper way
        I am not able to reconfigure weight of middle frame
        I want this window in full screen in middle frame
        Here you will notice column 1 taking minsize 30, can anyone solve this
        """
        for widget in self.middle_frame.winfo_children():
            widget.destroy()

        self.middle_frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.middle_frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

        second_screen_window = tk.Frame(self.middle_frame, bg='purple')
        second_screen_window.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')

left_frame = LeftFrame(root)
dynamic_window = DynamicWindow(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: put all code as one script so we could run it.

Comment: @furas now you can check it

Comment: i run it but I still don't understand what is the problem.  Maybe show on screenshot what you get and what you expected.

Comment: maybe better remove `screen` from grid ( `grid_forget()`) and put other one - instead of reconfiguring `screens`

Comment: i am not able to post image due to low reputation, @furas you can check screenshot through my google drive link https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CpNQiJjXfgRP8-dEodVXlJNILHERJ5qC/view?usp=sharing

Comment: in second screen you need `self.middle_frame.columnconfigure(1, minsize=0)` because it still use `self.middle_frame.columnconfigure(1, minsize=30)` from first frame.

Comment: @furas I already checked that, when I set minsize=0, then only middle_frame appear as a full green color instead of purple, please you can check it. And then first screen also don't work.

Comment: I get purple when I click button two times. And the same with other button - I have to click two times. I still don't know why it need to click two times but after two clicks and `self.middle_frame.columnconfigure(1, minsize=0)` it gives correct sizes .

Comment: Thank you so much @furas for your effort, If you find why we need to click two times please comment.

Comment: I found that when I click only once and next resize window then it redraws it with corrrect elements. It seems some problem with redrawing elements. But I would rather start from beginning and I would use separated `Frame` to create every `screen` - and then I would replace screens (Frames) without changing grid config.

Comment: @furas  Regarding - "I would rather start from beginning ...rest" I did exactly that in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made it all work for you. I lost interest in fighting with your code/method so, I completely rewrote the code from scratch and devised a different method. All of the issues that you highlighted have been resolved. The structure of my code should be much easier to work with. The main issue is that you were destroying children, but you weren't destroying the `column` and/or `row` that the children were in. You basically can't. Using `grid_forget()` even in conjunction with `destroy()` or `grid_remove()` doesn't seem to remove the grid cell.

**changes:**

- Every major widget has been separated into it's own class
- Names have been changed to reflect the actual purpose of each widget (to the best of my ability based on your example)
- We swap 'main display' widgets by removing/re-instating the entire widget ~ instead of destroying/recreating all of it's children
- a `lambda` is used in the button `command` to pass the desired 'main display' to the method that does the swapping
- we **never** use `super()` to instantiate a class. We specifically refer to the super by classname
- all `args` and `kwargs` are maintained, so we can treat our custom widgets like their super
- we only `import` **exactly** what we need (my preference)

The comments should tell you the rest, but if there is confusion, point it out to me in the comment section and I will respond with a more detailed explanation.

---

**widgets.py**

```
from tkinter import Frame, Button
from typing import List, Dict, Callable
from dataclasses import dataclass


#a simple "typedef" for storing menu button data
@dataclass
class MenuData_t:
    func:Callable        #method the command lambda will call
    buttons:List[Dict]   #Button(**kwargs)
    targets:List[Frame]  #'main display' to switch to
    griddata:List[Dict]  #.grid(**kwargs)


'''
this replaces your 'head_frame'
it also provides an interface to concoct all of the buttons that will swap 'main displays'
if you need other types of buttons you will need to manually create them in __init__
considerations have been made in init_displayswap_menu for existing buttons
'''
class MenuFrame(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs)

    def init_displayswap_menu(self, md:MenuData_t):
        c = len(self.winfo_children())
        for i, (b, t, g) in enumerate(zip(md.buttons, md.targets, md.griddata)):
            self.__dict__[f'swap_btn{i+1}'] = Button(self, command=lambda m=t: md.func(m), **b)
            self.__dict__[f'swap_btn{i+1}'].grid(row=0, column=i+c, **g)


#this replaces your "bottom_frame"
class Footer(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs)


#this replaces your "first_screen"
class PrimaryFrame(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs)

        self.chart   = Frame(self, bg='#4d4d4d')
        self.chart.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nswe')

        self.toolbar = Frame(self, bg='red')
        self.toolbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='nswe')

        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(1, minsize=30)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)


#this replaces your "second_screen"
class SecondaryFrame(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs)


#this replaces your "LeftFrame"
class Sidebar(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs)


#this replaces your "RightFrame" AND "DynamicWindow"
class MainFrame(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs)

        ##INSTANTIATE
        #menu
        self.menu = MenuFrame(self, bg='orange')
        self.menu.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')

        #main display
        self.current   = None #for storing currently used 'main display'

        self.primary   = PrimaryFrame(self, bg='green')
        self.secondary = SecondaryFrame(self, bg='purple')

        #footer
        self.footer = Footer(self, bg='orange')
        self.footer.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='nsew')

        ##UTILIZE
        #concoct main display swap menu
        '''    
        append accordingly to the 3 lists to create more buttons that will switch frames
        done this way so button creation can remain in MenuFrame but use remote data
        row, column and command are managed in MenuFrame
        '''
        self.menu.init_displayswap_menu(MenuData_t(
            self.main_display,              #method the command lambda will call
            [{'text':'Primary'},            #Button(**kwargs)
             {'text':'Secondary'},
            ],
            [self.primary,                  #'main display' to switch to
             self.secondary,
            ],
            [{'sticky':'nswe','ipadx':20},  #.grid(**kwargs)
             {'sticky':'nswe','ipadx':20},
            ]
        ))

        #init main display
        '''
        I could have called main_display directly but this illustrates 2 things
        1: how to virtually click a button
        2: how to access the buttons that MenuFrame created in it's __dict__
        '''
        self.menu.swap_btn1.invoke()

        #configure grid
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, minsize=30)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(2, minsize=30)

    #replaces your 'first_screen' AND 'second_screen' methods
    def main_display(self, frame):
        if self.current is not frame:       #only swap if we aren't requesting the current 'main display'
            if self.current: 
                self.current.grid_remove()  #remove current from the grid, instead of destroy
    
            self.current = frame            #set new current and add it to the grid
            self.current.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='nsew')
```

**main.py**

```
from win32api import GetMonitorInfo, MonitorFromPoint
from widgets import Sidebar, MainFrame
from tkinter import Tk


#This is your "root"
class Application(Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        Sidebar(self, bg='red').grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nswe')
        MainFrame(self, bg='black').grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='nswe')

        #configure grid
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, minsize=350)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)


#kick off the entire app with proper PEP8
if __name__ == '__main__':
    monitor_info = GetMonitorInfo(MonitorFromPoint((0, 0)))['Work']

    app = Application()
    app.title("Manish Pushpam's Bad-Ass Application")
    app.geometry(f'{monitor_info[2]}x{monitor_info[3]}')
    app.minsize(800, 600)
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you so much @michael-guidry, But seriously title. Ohh noo. Again thanks. You taught me lot of things.

Comment: @Manish Pushpam ~ lol, I see. I put the code back AND I added the reason that yours wasn't working. If I solved your problem it would be very much appreciated if you accept my answer.

Comment: Yes @Michael-Guidry, sir you absolutely solved my problem, I am learning tkinter, Sir you guided me how I can write code in pro way. Thank you so much for your fantastic answer.

Comment: your welcome sir, This was my 1st question, I was unaware how this website work. Thank you so much sir you taught me a lot of things today.

Comment: @Manish Pushpam  ~ I'll check your profile from time to time to see if you have more questions regarding your project. If I can help, I will. You're welcome. The site works on reputation, which you get from having accepted answer and up-votes to an answer. For instance: You accepted me and I went up 15 points. I up-voted you and you went up 10. Higher reputation equals more privileges.

Comment: Hello @Michael-Guidry, Sir can you please solve my latest question.

Comment: @ManishPushpam ~ by the time I woke up it was already solved